# Binary XML file line #138: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater, drawerlayout, navigationview

I am running into this error and I've tried every solution I've found posted on here/other forums. Chances are that I've missed something obvious. I'm completely stuck, would really appreciate any help or insight. 
I'll post all the files that are relevant to the existing 'solutions' I've found

To Test for yourself (Project = 490TermProject) [490TermProject](https://github.com/chasemcintyre105/Sample-Code-Repository/blob/master/490TermProject.zip)

LogCat:

```
**Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #138: Binary 
XML file line #138: Error inflating class 
android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                  at 
com.example.chase.termproject.cardFragmentList.onCreateView
(cardFragmentList.java:59)**
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.chase.termproject">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".tag_sending"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".tag_received">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data 
android:mimeType="application/com.example.chase.termproject"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".cardPagerActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".cardListActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/CardsToolbarTheme"
        >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".resumePagerActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".resumeListActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Styles:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#3f51b5</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#004b96</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="CardViewStyle" parent="CardView">
    <item name="android:height">120sp</item>
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">2dp</item>
    <item name="cardElevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/silverMetallic</item>
    <item name="cardPreventCornerOverlap">false</item>
    <item name="android:foreground">? 
android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="CardsToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#004b96</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#FFFF31</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

card_fragment_list XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:style="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/cards_drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/cards_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/CardsToolbarTheme"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100"
            >
            <View
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cards_toolbar_menuImage"
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                android:src="@drawable/menu_icon_black"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="10"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cards_toolbar_textview"
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="70"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/cards_toolbar_search_button"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:hint="@string/filter_search_for_keywords"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/cards_toolbar_search_button"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                android:src="@drawable/search_icon"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:background="?actionBarItemBackground"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_light"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="87"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <View
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/card_button"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="45"
            android:elevation="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/main_activity_database_bg"
            android:text="@string/BusinessCards"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resume_button"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="45"
            android:elevation="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/main_activity_database_bg"
            android:text="@string/Resumes"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/cards_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/cards_drawer_view"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/result_nav_header_cards"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/actionBoxBlue"
    >
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

card fragment list Activity(shortened to contain only relevant code):

```
public class cardFragmentList extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView cardRecycerView;
private Button cardButton;
private Button resumeButton;
private cardAdapter cAdapter;
private NavigationView cards_navigation_view;
private EditText cards_toolbar_edittext;
private DrawerLayout cards_drawer_layout;
private Toolbar cards_toolbar;
private ImageButton cards_search_button;
private ImageView cards_toolbar_menuImage;
private List<businessCardItem> bCards;
private List<businessCardItem> tempBCards;
private int filterFlags;
private int previousFilterFlags;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_fragment_list, container, 
false);
    bCards = 
cardDbConnection.getDbConnection(getActivity()).getBusinessCards();
    this.cardRecycerView = (RecyclerView) 
view.findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    this.cardRecycerView.setLayoutManager(new 
LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    this.cardButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.card_button);
    this.resumeButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.resume_button);
    this.resumeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), 
resumeListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    this.cards_search_button = (ImageButton) 
view.findViewById(R.id.cards_toolbar_search_button);
    this.cards_toolbar_edittext = (EditText) 
view.findViewById(R.id.cards_toolbar_textview);
    this.cards_drawer_layout = (DrawerLayout) 
view.findViewById(R.id.cards_drawer_layout);
    this.cards_navigation_view = (NavigationView) 
view.findViewById(R.id.cards_navigation_view);

this.cards_navigation_view.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.cards_menu_group, 
true, false);
    this.cards_toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.cards_toolbar);

    this.cards_toolbar_menuImage = (ImageView) 
view.findViewById(R.id.cards_toolbar_menuImage);
    this.cards_toolbar_menuImage.setOnClickListener(new 
View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cards_drawer_layout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });

    cards_navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem 
item) {
                    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.cards_nav_name) {
                        item.setIcon(R.drawable.check_box_on);

cards_navigation_view.getMenu().getItem(1).setIcon(R.drawable.check_box_off);

cards_navigation_view.getMenu().getItem(2).setIcon(R.drawable.check_box_off);
                        filterFlags = 1;
                    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.cards_nav_phone) {
                        item.setIcon(R.drawable.check_box_on);

cards_navigation_view.getMenu().getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.check_box_off);

cards_navigation_view.getMenu().getItem(2).setIcon(R.drawable.check_box_off);
                        filterFlags = 2;
                    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.cards_nav_email) {
                        item.setIcon(R.drawable.check_box_on);

cards_navigation_view.getMenu().getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.check_box_off);

cards_navigation_view.getMenu().getItem(1).setIcon(R.drawable.check_box_off);
                        filterFlags = 4;
                    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.cards_nav_apply) {
                        filterResults();
                        cards_drawer_layout.closeDrawers();
                    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.cards_nav_clear) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 
cards_navigation_view.getMenu().size() - 2; i++) {

cards_navigation_view.getMenu().getItem(i).setIcon(R.drawable.check_box_off);
                        }
                        filterFlags = 0;
                        filterResults();
                        cards_drawer_layout.closeDrawers();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
    this.cards_search_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

searchCardsForString(cards_toolbar_edittext.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    updateUI();
    return view;
}

private void searchCardsForString(String key) {
    if (key.length() > 0) {
        List<businessCardItem> tempCards = new ArrayList<>();
        if (tempBCards == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < bCards.size(); i++) {
                if (searchCardForKey(key, bCards.get(i)) == 1) {
                    tempCards.add(bCards.get(i));
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < tempBCards.size(); i++) {
                if (searchCardForKey(key, tempBCards.get(i)) == 1) {
                    tempCards.add(tempBCards.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        tempBCards = tempCards;
    } else {
        tempBCards = bCards;
    }
    updateUI();
}

private int searchCardForKey(String key, businessCardItem card) {
    if (card.getCardName().contains(key)) {
        return 1;
    } else if (card.getCardEmail().contains(key)) {
        return 1;
    } else if (card.getCardPhone().contains(key)) {
        return 1;
    } else if (card.getCardTags().contains(key)) {
        return 1;
    } else if (card.getCardExperiences().contains(key)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

private void filterResults() {
    previousFilterFlags = filterFlags;

    if (filterFlags == 0) {
        tempBCards = bCards;
    } else {
        tempBCards = new ArrayList<>();
        tempBCards.addAll(bCards);

        if (filterFlags == 1) {
            //by name
            ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < tempBCards.size(); i++) {
                nameList.add(tempBCards.get(i).getCardName());
            }
            tempBCards.clear();
            Collections.sort(nameList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
            for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < bCards.size(); z++) {
                    if 
(nameList.get(i).compareTo(bCards.get(z).getCardName()) == 0) {
                        tempBCards.add(bCards.get(z));
                        z = bCards.size();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (filterFlags == 2) {
            //by phone
            ArrayList<String> phoneList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < tempBCards.size(); i++) {
                phoneList.add(tempBCards.get(i).getCardPhone());
            }
            tempBCards.clear();
            Collections.sort(phoneList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
            for (int i = 0; i < phoneList.size(); i++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < bCards.size(); z++) {
                    if 
(phoneList.get(i).compareTo(bCards.get(z).getCardPhone()) == 0) {
                        tempBCards.add(bCards.get(z));
                        z = bCards.size();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (filterFlags == 4) {
            //by email
            ArrayList<String> emailList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < tempBCards.size(); i++) {
                emailList.add(tempBCards.get(i).getCardEmail());
            }
            tempBCards.clear();
            Collections.sort(emailList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
            for (int i = 0; i < emailList.size(); i++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < bCards.size(); z++) {
                    if 
 (emailList.get(i).compareTo(bCards.get(z).getCardEmail()) == 0) {
                        tempBCards.add(bCards.get(z));
                        z = bCards.size();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    updateUI();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateUI();
}

private void updateUI() {
    if (tempBCards == null) {
        cardDbConnection cDBcon = 
cardDbConnection.getDbConnection(getActivity());
        bCards = cDBcon.getBusinessCards();

        if (this.cAdapter == null) {
            this.cAdapter = new cardAdapter(bCards);
            this.cardRecycerView.setAdapter(cAdapter);
        } else {
            this.cAdapter.setCards(bCards);
            this.cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } else {
        if (this.cAdapter == null) {
            this.cAdapter = new cardAdapter(tempBCards);
            this.cardRecycerView.setAdapter(cAdapter);
        } else {
            this.cAdapter.setCards(tempBCards);
            this.cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Build.Gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.chase.termproject"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
}
ext{
    supportLibVersion = '27.1.0'
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-            
  core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    // CardView
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    // Picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    // Horizontal Picker
    implementation 'com.wefika:horizontal-picker:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:27.1.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
}
```

result_nav_header_cards XML

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/drawer_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@color/actionBoxBlue"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/filter_header_cards"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What does your `result_nav_header_cards.xml` layout file look like?

Comment: I've added result_nav_header_cards.xml to the end of the original post
 Thanks so much for the help

Comment: I've also added a link to a GitHub repository where you can download and test this for yourself - at the top of the original post

Comment: `InflateException` itself doesn't tell you much. It's a wrapper Exception. Look for the last `Caused by:` section in the stack trace.